# Generate random number of points inside polygon extent in python

Tags: random, polygon, arcpy, point-in-polygon

I need to generate fixed random points inside a polygons. For that, I need to generate random points inside the extent of polygons and then select the ones that are inside the polygon boundary later. how can i generate points inside the given extent of polygon in python ; where extent is max x, max y and minx, min y in meters

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is built into arcpy's CreateRandomPoints_management tool; you can either pass the extent of your polygons layer in or use the polygons layer to constrain the points to only within the polygons.